# cron job for sphinx indexing is not working but working with command line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, whenever-capistrano

I am using rails 3 and trying to update cron job after certain time interval. When I used RAILS_ENV=production rake ts:index, it is working fine but sphinx is not indexing with cron job. Wating for your solution.

Below are my codes for your reference:

```
gem 'whenever', :require => false
```

schedule.rb

```
set :output, "/var/www/somesitename.com/public_html/current/log/cron_log.log"
set :environment, "production"

every 1.minutes do
  rake "ts:rebuild RAILS_ENV=production"
end
```

I check this command

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog |grep CRON
```

and i got following output which tell cron job is running

```
May 22 16:40:01 anveshna /USR/SBIN/CRON[31133]: (shivraj) CMD (/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/www/xproject/public_html/releases/20140522093026 && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake ts:rebuild RAILS_ENV=production --silent >> /var/www/demo.anveshnatech.com/public_html/current/log/cron_log.log 2>&1')
May 22 16:40:01 anveshna /USR/SBIN/CRON[31134]: (shivraj) CMD (/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/www/xproject/public_html/releases/20140522093026 && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake ts:rebuild RAILS_ENV=production --silent >> /var/www/demo.anveshnatech.com/public_html/current/log/cron_log.log 2>&1')
```

output of crontab -e

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /var/www/xproject/public_html
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/www/xproject/public_html/releases/20140522093026 && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake ts:rebuild RAILS_EN$

# End Whenever generated tasks for: /var/www/xproject/public_html
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /var/www/xproject/public_html/releases/20140521084223/config/schedule.rb
0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/www/xproject/public_html/r$

# End Whenever generated tasks for: /var/www/xproject/public_html/releases/20140521084223/config/schedule.rb

# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /var/www/xproject/public_html/releases/20140522093026/config/schedule.rb
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/www/xproject/public_html/releases/20140522093026 && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake ts:rebuild RAILS_EN$

# End Whenever generated tasks for: /var/www/xproject/public_html/releases/20140522093026/config/schedule.rb
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's in cron_log.log?  Those lines don't mean it's working, just that it tried.

Comment: In current directory, log file, there is not cron_log.log.

Comment: Nothing in /var/www/demo.anveshnatech.com/public_html/current/log/cron_log.log ?

Comment: yes you are right @PhilipHallstrom

Comment: I'd suggest dropping that --silent and whatever else is needed to generate some output so that log file fills up with something useful.

Comment: "env |grep PATH" provide a path, which i have placed in first line of the crontab. It works like a charm. :)